# Programming syntax and techniques

Tags: oop, c++11

As a beginner programmer, a lot of the problems I have seem to come from a lack of knowledge in certain built in classes, or not knowing that the question I have can be handled by an already created classes (such as string). How can I get around this? Or is this just something that improves with time, learning more about the language as a whole as I practice programming?

Comment: Are you aware of the many references for the pre-existing C++ classes, such as http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/?

Comment: I am, but sometimes I have a problem that I do not know how to approach. Then I might ask another programmer and stack overflow and only then do I find out that I could have used std::string::whatever

Comment: Good to start with the Standard library (for which I'd recommend [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) over cplusplus.com) and [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/).  Some of it will be impossible to understand the use of, but just run an eye over the content every now and then and you'll find more and more.

Answer (score 2):

Research and practice mostly.  Before you do something, Google it to see if there's a class for that already.

This is a useful reference page to start with: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's something that will improve with times. I will suggest that you read the documentation for the class that you are working on ex: string http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ you read each function so you  have a knowledge of what this class can do. can it split a word? can it find a word by a given index? if not than I know I have to build that function.